# jstl tag to increment date in table header i.e from date to to date

Tags: jsp, jstl

can any help how to increment date using jstl 
     i.e in table header i need to print date from "FROM DATE" to "TO DATE " Ex:some one selected  11-10-2013 to 18-10-2013 for some report parts(distance travelled) i need to display each day report so how to do this

Comment: Do it in Java, in your controller.

Comment: please show code it is impossible to help you otherwise some punctation and capital letters would be nice your question is a little hard to read you can [edit] your question to clarify